# What kind of object is a DAO?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dao

I would like to know if a DAO qualifies as a helper or as a model?

I want to clarify that I understand DAO as a Data Access Object, an object that in my case allows to connect to the database.

I'm working on a PHP project with the Zend suggested project structure and want to be sure where should I place a DAO that helps me to connect to the database.

Thanks.

Comment: well as my professor once said to me "you need to define your terms young man"

Comment: Hey Dagon I just want to know what describes the best a dao class knowing that is just a class that provides connection to the db.

Comment: And also knowing that you can choose from helper, model, controller (not sure that will apply).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, what connects to the database in the MVC patterns is the Model.

I strongly suggest you to read the [Wikipedia article about MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and start working with Zend following the tutorials of [ZF1](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html) or [ZF2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/index.html).

Greets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your advice Saso222.